# Why threads doesn't accept this input?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I was doing a project that uses threads to sum some matrix but at the time of creating the threads and adding the params it always shows up the same error. Any ideas?

```
void sum(std::vector <double>& matrix, std::vector <double>& other) {
    for (auto i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        matrix[i] += other[i];
    }
}
```

here it is the operation that threads should do.

```
std::vector <double>* mat1 = new std::vector <double>[15];
std::vector <double>* mat2 = new std::vector <double>[15];
std::vector <std::thread*> threads;

for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++) {
    sum(mat1[j], mat2[j]);                                          //this works;
    threads.push_back(new std::thread(sum,mat1[j],mat2[j]));        //this dont why?;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your use of `new` seems very wrong. There should be no need for any `new` in this code. Raw `new`s are rarely needed in modern C++ and [should be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/why-should-c-programmers-minimize-use-of-new). `std::vector <std::thread*> threads;` can be `std::vector <std::thread> threads;`, the pointer is not needed. Similarly for `mat1` and `mat2`. That aside, either variant has undefined behavior, because you are trying to index into the `std::vector<double>`s in `sum`, but they are empty. Please provide a complete [repro], including the error message.

Comment: Re: "it always shows ... the same error" -- what error is that? Include the error message in the question.

Comment: Your question can not be answered unless you edit to include the error message and minimal example code.

Answer (score 1):

To get it to compile, change:

```
std::thread(sum,mat1[j],mat2[j])
```

to:

```
std::thread(sum, std::ref(mat1[j]), std::ref(mat2[j]))
```

Example: https://godbolt.org/z/Ek-cnm

But there are multiple problems with your question and code besides just getting it to compile, please listen to what other have said in the comments.